# 'the love of nature' (1. nature can love or 2. can be loved?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> 'the love of nature'

1. nature can love or 2. can be loved? or 3. both?

The phrase above is confusing.

the love of your country : country is loved here (passive)

the love of God : God is not loved here (God is the subject who gives love)

Answer (score 1):

In the phrase *the love of nature*, it is nature that is loved.

I can't think of a context where nature itself can love.

As to *the love of God*, God can be either the subject or object of the verb *love*.

Comment: But we do sometimes say “Nature abhors a vacuum.”

Comment: That's true. In figurative speech I guess you could say, "nature loves filling empty spaces." Still, I don't think any sense like that is intended in the common phrase "the love of nature".